# Why prices on input fields don't work after adding a new fields dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I'm building an invoice app with jQuery. The application can calculate prices automatically and also generate new input fields when pressing on the "ADD LINE" button. The problem I have is that the very first row of input fields always works,but as soon as you start adding new fields, the prices and quantity numbers are not being calculated by the app at all. The worst of all is that the console doesn't mention any errors on my script so I really don'y know whats going on.

Thanks,

Here's my code:

```
// Core functions for calculations
$('input[name=r],input[name=p]').change(function(e) {
    var total = 0;
    var $row = $(this).parent();
    var rate = $row.find('input[name=r]').val();
    var pack = $row.find('input[name=p]').val();
    total = parseFloat(rate * pack)*1;

    //update the row total
    $row.find('.amount').html((total).toFixed(2));

    var total_amount = 0;
    var tax = 1.06;
 $('.amount').each(function() {
    //Get the value
    var am= $(this).text();
    console.log(am);
    //if it's a number add it to the total
    if (IsNumeric(am)) {
      total_amount += parseFloat(am, 10);
    }

    // Get total with tax
      taxTotal = (tax * total_amount);
    });
    // Total with out tax
    $('.total_amount').html('<p> $ '+(total_amount).toFixed(2)+'</p>');

    // Total with tax
    $('.after_tax').html('<p> $ '+(taxTotal).toFixed(2)+'</p>');

});

//if it's a number add it to the total
function IsNumeric(input) {
    return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
}


// generate a new row
function AddRow(){
    var wrapper = $('.input_fields_wrap');
    var addButton = $('#add_row');

    var x = 1;
    $(addButton).click(function(){
    x++;
    $(wrapper).append('<div><input class="description" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Enter Description" value=""/><input  name="r" class="rate qty" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="0" size="5" value=""/><input  name="p" class="pack price" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="$ 0.00" size="5" value=""/><span  id="amount" class="amount">0.00</span><a class="btn btn-danger removeRow">X</a></div>');
});

// Remove row
$(wrapper).on('click', '.removeRow', function(){
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });
}
AddRow();
```

Comment: a [mcve] would be great

Comment: That's cause after adding the new elements you need again to get them from the DOM. OR or or or Use correctly the `.on()` method with event delegation.

Comment: I just posted my code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change event isn't bound to any dynamically-added input elements. Use jQuery's `.on()` method on an ancestor selector:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[name=r],input[name=p]', (function(e) {
    // ...
```

Ideally you should choose the closest ancestor to the inputs that exists in the DOM when the page is rendered.